# Copying and remoting using powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, sdk

Hi all I'd like to copy a file to a computer and remote into said machine 
and run a single command then gather the output file of that command. I've
been tasked to use Powershell to copy and remote into the machines.
I use this page to help start me out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C
The program I'm using is .net 4 and has to stay that way. I first installed the windows sdk 3.5 then when the code didnt work I installed sdk 4.0 but I still get
the same error in my answer string: "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.\r\n"
Thanks for the help
Casey

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
// open it
runspace.Open();
// create a pipeline and feed it the script text
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module BitsTransfer" + Environment.NewLine + "Start-BitsTransfer -Source " + filename + " -Destination \\\\" + host + "\\" + uploadtodir + "\\"+Environment.NewLine);
// add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
// remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script
// "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
// execute the script

Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
try
{
   results = pipeline.Invoke();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
}

// close the runspace
runspace.Close();
// convert the script result into a single string

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}

string answer= stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the App.config file of the project you need to add this:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

If you don't have an App.config file just create one.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: if you have to create an App.config file you also have to change the project to .net 3.5 and then change it to 4. It doesnt read the change in the app file untill the change in the project solution is made. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx